# Azure AD B2C - P1 / P2 - Feature comparison - MFA Costing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am not able to find a Microsoft link documenting the features  comparison matrix between Azure AD B2C P1 and P2 . This is the only [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/) I could find. My assumption is that if I want to do a quick estimate on MFA (based on risk based scenarios) costing with Azure AD B2C I would have to use the P2 MAU pricing model along with MFA events (cost for sms / phone events).  Could someone confirm my understanding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are correct.

The difference is:

> Premium P2 features include all the Premium P1 features and
> market-leading Identity Protection and Identity Governance controls,
> such as **risk-based** Conditional Access policies and Identity Protection
> reporting for Azure AD B2C.

Considering the **risk based scenarios**, you should choose Premium P2. Note that a flat fee of $0.03 is billed for each SMS/Phone-based multi-factor authentication attempt.

Comment: If I go with P1  I will be sending an MFA on every authentication.  Am I correct ?

Comment: @srini I don't quite understand what you mean. Sending an MFA on every authentication depends on if you enable MFA in your user flow.